# Windows 11 net rpc shutdown

Tags: windows-11, remote-shutdown

Any idea why net rpc shutdown command would not work on windows 11?

I have 3 windows 10 PCs and this works perfectly, however, on my two windows 11 devices it does not.

All PCs had been configured in the same way. I'm starting to believe that there might be an extra security setting I need to change for windows 11

The shutdown command is as follows:

```
net rpc shutdown -f -I 192.168.0.150 -U user%password
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
[08/10/2022, 08:02:26] [Eddy Laptop] [NetworkDevice] Error: Command failed: net rpc shutdown -f -I 192.168.0.174 -U user%password
Could not connect to server 192.168.0.174
The username or password was not correct.
```

Answer (score 2):

On the remote host, disable Simple File Sharing in
*Folder Options > View*.
Scroll to the bottom of the list and uncheck
"Use Sharing Wizard (Recommended)".

File and Printer Sharing must be enabled in
*Settings > Network & Internet > Status > Network and Sharing Centre >
Change advanced sharing settings*.

The firewall must allow File and Printer Sharing through in
*Start > Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security > Inbound Rules*.

Comment: There are so many rules start with `File and Printer Sharing` do i need to enable all of them.

Comment: Yes, enable all of them. Some may not be needed, but they are not harmful.

Answer (score 1):

Please check again Window's account.
As my case, I used default of the Window: `Administrator` without password. So my command line:

```
net rpc shutdown -I ${ip} -U Administrator%
```

Remember that, you must disable `Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only` from the Window system.
To do it, follow: 
*Edit group policy > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only > Disable*